# navigation bar 'highlight' function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've written JQuery that highlights the 'About', 'My Projects', or 'Contact Me' text on the navigation bar when the corresponding page section is being viewed. In order to do this I'm using a scroll() event listener:

```
$(document).scroll(function myFuction() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $("#contactMe").offset().top) {
        $("#contactButton").addClass("active");
        $("#projectButton").removeClass("active");
        $("#aboutButton").removeClass("active");       
    } else if ( $(document).scrollTop() > $("#portfolio").offset().top && $(document).scrollTop() < $("#contactMe").offset().top) {
        $("#contactButton").removeClass("active");
        $("#projectButton").addClass("active");
        $("#aboutButton").removeClass("active");
    } else if ( $(document).scrollTop() > $("#about").offset().top && $(document).scrollTop() < $("#portfolio").offset().top)  {
        $("#contactButton").removeClass("active");
        $("#projectButton").removeClass("active");
        $("#aboutButton").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

When the user scrolls, the function checks to see where the top of the page is by scrollTop(), and then adds or removes the "active" class which effectively highlights the appropriate text.

I understand though that having an action performed within an event listener is generally a bad idea, but I'm not sure how else to go about accomplishing what I'm trying to do. Perhaps I'm somehow re-inventing the wheel here?

I would have imagined the Bootstrap library would have had a pre-packaged class for this, but no luck in finding that.

Comment: [Bootstrap Scrollspy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)

Comment: $("#contactButton").removeClass("active");
    $("#projectButton").addClass("active");
    $("#aboutButton").removeClass("active");

Why you copy and paste code multiple time? This could be optimize with a specific class for each voice of the navigationbar and when you're on the specific one, you can remove from the others and add just on the one you are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get some class for all those items, cache them as jQuery collection, and on scroll check if any of them is in viewport - based on this you can perform needed action.

Fast demo:

```js
var $items = $('.item')
var $window = $(window);
var $document = $(document);

function inViewport(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    rect.bottom > 0 &&
    rect.right > 0 &&
    rect.left < $window.width() &&
    rect.top < $window.height()
  );
};

$document.on('scroll', function(){
  $items.each(function(){
    if(inViewport(this)) {
      $items.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      return false;
    }
  })
}).trigger('scroll');
```

```css
.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.item.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item"><span>#1</span></div>
<div class="item"><span>#2</span></div>
<div class="item"><span>#3</span></div>
<div class="item"><span>#4</span></div>
<div class="item"><span>#5</span></div>
<div class="item"><span>#6</span></div>
<div class="item"><span>#7</span></div>
<div class="item"><span>#8</span></div>
<div class="item"><span>#9</span></div>
<div class="item"><span>#10</span></div>
```

It's also a good idea to throttle scroll calls
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle
or your own implementation.

Comment: thanks for the example - do you see any performance issues with the code the way I currently have it?

Comment: Definitely your code can be improved.
Not caching jQuery object cause it to "search" for it every time you call `scroll`.
As far as i know jQuery does not get cached by default, so in the worst case your code will search for node 14 time per scroll call, and scroll event can be fired hundred of times per scroll.

Also using if-else blocks to check which element is active is very hard to scale and read.

Comment: @MateuszStaniuk thank you for caching jQuery objects. More answers need to demonstrate this easy to implement performance enhancement. Oh and +1 for using the `$` prefix convention to identify the contents of the variable as a jQuery object/collection.